# Docker CE upgrade on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)

Tags: linux, docker

Trying to install docker on linux machine, getting some strange error.

when i install docker ce - dependency is docker-ce-rootless-extras​,
when i install docker-ce-rootless-extras - dependency is docker-ce

The error

```
[root@XXXX yum.repos.d]# rpm -ivh https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-20.10.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-20.10.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.8moqkE: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 621e9f35: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        docker-ce-rootless-extras is needed by docker-ce-3:20.10.0-3.el7.x86_64
[root@XXXX yum.repos.d]# rpm -ivh https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.m7QmNS: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 621e9f35: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        docker-ce is needed by docker-ce-rootless-extras-0:20.10.0-3.el7.x86_64
        fuse-overlayfs >= 0.7 is needed by docker-ce-rootless-extras-0:20.10.0-3.el7.x86_64
        slirp4netns >= 0.4 is needed by docker-ce-rootless-extras-0:20.10.0-3.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: First, two of your packages are outdated, so consider updating those packages first. Then see again whether its a circular dependency (a needs b, but b needs a).

Comment: Yes . I tried with latest one as well - docker-ce-20.10.5-3.el7.x86_64.rpm and docker-ce-cli-20.10.5-3.el7.x86_64.rpm getting same dependency  error .

Answer (score 1):

issue is that Docker CE  is not officially supported on REHL.

wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.107-3.el7.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -i container-selinux-2.107.el7.noarch.rpm

wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/slirp4netns-0.4.3-4.el7_8.x86_64.rpm

#Set up the Docker CE repository on RHEL:
sudo yum install -y yum-utils
sudo yum install -y device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
sudo yum makecache fast
yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
#Start Docker:
sudo systemctl start docker

#Test your Docker CE installation:
sudo docker run hello-world